# Can't sudo gem uninstall (you don't have write permissions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, rubygems, uninstallation

I'm having trouble removing a gem from my system. When i ask gem where RedCloth is installed it says this:

```
    pteng01:trunk mike$ gem list -d RedCloth

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    RedCloth (3.0.4)
        Author: why the lucky stiff
        Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/redcloth
        Homepage: http://www.whytheluckystiff.net/ruby/redcloth/
        Installed at: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

        RedCloth is a module for using Textile and Markdown in Ruby. Textile
        and Markdown are text formats.  A very simple text format. Another
        stab at making readable text that can be converted to HTML.
    pteng01:trunk mike$
```

I tried

```
sudo gem uninstall --install-dir /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

and i get this error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin directory.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran

```
gem cleanup
```

and then enter

```
gem list -d RedCloth
```

which shows this

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

RedCloth (4.2.3)
    Author: Jason Garber
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/redcloth
    Homepage: http://redcloth.org
    Installed at: /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

    RedCloth-4.2.3 - Textile parser for Ruby. http://redcloth.org/
```

looks like it wasnt really at the previous location.

Comment: If `gem cleanup` was run and fixed the issue, you probably had several versions of the gem and the cleanup command removed all the but most recent.

Comment: yeah that was the case, i was trying to remove the older version so i could go with the new one and have peace of mind im not cluttering up my system.